# React-navigation- dependencies (Error while install NPM navigation dependencies package installation)

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation, npm-install, react-navigation-v5

when I install this package

1 . npm install @react-native-community/masked-view .

it shows error like this

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: Sample_pro@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/masked-view@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-21T03_52_51_024Z-debug.log

-----How should I solve this problem-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther error message is telling you that
your proj is using `react` @ 17.0.1 version while `@react-native-community/masked-view` 0.1.10 has a dependency of `react` @ 16.

To solve it, you can choose one of the followings:

1. upgrade @react-native-community/masked-view to the latest package which is accepting react@16 and react@17
2. downgrade your root project's react version to 16

Comment: sir how should I upgrade @react-native-community/masked-view to the latest ?

Comment: change the version in package.json. the latest one is 0.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

please remove package-lock.json file and try to install again hope it will work.

Comment: Did removing package-lock.json file effects my Project??

Comment: removing package-lock.json would lost your installed package version. then npm will get the latest package version following the version in package.json. It won't help in your case as you got version conflict in package.json already.